# C++ wcout unocode(Cyrillic, Japanese)

Tags: windows, c++11, console, locale

In my application I use *Cyrillic* and *Japanese* characters. When I use:

```
_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT).
```

On OS Windows - my output data looks like:

> 1. cyrillic : Привет
> 2. japanese : ???

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must install the Japanese locale on you machine.

For your OS, i.e Windows, check [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-system-locale#1TC=windows-7).

[This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb895996.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is a list of locales for Windows.

Comment: This answer would be even better if it included or linked to instructions on how to install the Japanese locale on Windows.